# HTML Agility Pack + DataGrids

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I'm trying to understand how to use the HTML Agility Pack on the VB.net library.

So far I have achieved what I wanted, but I'm trying to tidy it up because at the moment there seems to be a lot of white space.

For example my code is :

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load  
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim Item As String
        Dim URL As String = "https://ge.2007hq.com/item/" & TextBox1.Text & ""
        Dim ItemXPath As String = "//*[@class='chart']"
        Dim Web As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb
        Dim Doc As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
        Doc = Web.Load(Url)
        For Each itemResult As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode In Doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(ItemXPath)
            Item = itemResult.InnerText
            RichTextBox1.Text = itemResult.InnerText    
        Next
    End Sub
End Class`
```

Output is:

```
  Price Changes Since


        3
        3 Days Ago
        74 (-10.8%)



        7
        7 Days Ago
        86 (-23.3%)



        30
        30 Days Ago
        95 (-30.5%)



        3M
        3 Months Ago
        368 (-82.1%)



        6M
        6 Months Ago
        140 (-52.9%)



        1Y
        1 Year Ago
        223 (-70.4%)
```

What my end goal should be to achieve is to have each section in a `DataGrid` with the Columns

- "Day"
- "Amount"
- "Percent"

I can't even get the received text into a `TextBox` so seriously struggling with `DataGrid`s.

Any ideas if this is even possible?

Comment: You will have to create more sophisticated XPath based on your source's HTML, so you can reach to the deeper tags with have the content that is meaningful to you (without empty spaces), and so you'll get this data delivered in small chunks that you can organize in columns and rows as it suits your needs.

Comment: Any ideas or information on how i would learn how to do more sophisticated xpaths?

Comment: double post.....

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the source HTML of the page you are reading from? Apart from that, I use to check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp) when I need to recycle myself on XPath (I'm not required to create new code with XPath very often).

Comment: I dont seem to be able to edit my original post. http://pastebin.com/2Ufcbs0n Is the page source and the section I'm trying to obtain is starting from line 159 to 199. Hope that helps

Comment: Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, try this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    Dim URL As String = "https://ge.2007hq.com/item/" & "" & ""
    Dim ChartXPath As String = "//ul[@class='chart']"
    Dim Web As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb
    Dim Doc As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
    Doc = Web.Load(URL)
    Dim N1, N2, N3 As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode, T1, T2, T3 As String
    For Each chartResult As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode In Doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(ChartXPath)
        If chartResult.InnerText.Contains("Price Changes Since") Then
            For Each itemResult In chartResult.SelectNodes("//li")
                N1 = itemResult.SelectNodes("//div[@class='calendar']/span").FirstOrDefault
                N2 = itemResult.SelectNodes("//b/@title").FirstOrDefault
                N3 = itemResult.SelectNodes("//div[@class='pull-right']").FirstOrDefault
                If N1 Is Nothing Then T1 = "" Else T1 = N1.InnerText
                If N2 Is Nothing Then T2 = "" Else T2 = N2.InnerText
                If N3 Is Nothing Then T3 = "" Else T3 = N3.InnerText
                sb.AppendLine(String.Format("T1:{0}, T2:{1}, T3:{2}", T1, T2, T3))
            Next
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox(sb.ToString)
End Sub
```

Comment: `For Each chartResult As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode In Doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(ChartXPath)` Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: I've sorted that out so i am getting  T1:23, T2:3 Days Ago, T3:5,924,518 (0.0%)
T1:23, T2:3 Days Ago, T3:5,924,518 (0.0%)
T1:23, T2:3 Days Ago, T3:5,924,518 (0.0%)
T1:23, T2:3 Days Ago, T3:5,924,518 (0.0%)

Comment: Glad to know :-)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm curious is there a more simpler way to parse text from html page rather than using HtmlAgilityPack? It seems awfully fragile and complicated.

Comment: There's a *different* way, can't say it is *simpler*. You could load the page with a WebBrowser control, and get its .Document property that allows reading it through HtmlDocument and HtmlElement classes